# How to grab the underlying javascript element of an Element in WebdriverIO to be able to execute native js functions?

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

For example in plain javascript you can do this:

```
obj = document.querySelector('li#wmd-help-button')
obj.getBoundingClientRect()
```

How to execute getBoundingClientRect or similar functions when you have the Element via WebdriverIO, namely you have the object: `const elem = $('li#wmd-help-button')`

The question is not specific for `getBoundingClientRect` but refers to all such functions which are not directly accessible from the `Element` class of Webdriverio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Webdriver.IO's `browser.execute` method. https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/execute.

It essentially allows you to execute your script in the current page's context. Based on the code you provided, it could look like this:

```
 const boundingClientRect = await browser.execute(async () => {
       let obj = document.querySelector('li#wmd-help-button');
       return obj.getBoundingClientRect();
 });
```

Comment: I wish it was easier but you are correct, the execute is the way to go. Many thanks